Serial framing code for Vacuum Fluorescent Display via ESP32
I'm trying to write some code for a VFD I got off eBay, and I'm having trouble with the serial framing and figuring out how to pulse the write pins and device select pins to send hex data for it to print. I have a datasheet from the manufacturer and I'm certain that I have the physical circuit wired correctly.
My current code is here
#include <Arduino.h>

const int wrPin = 23;
const int csPin = 18;
const int buttonPin = 21;
const int aoPin = 19;
int currentState;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2, 16, 17);
  pinMode(wrPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(csPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(aoPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(wrPin, 0); //set 23 low
  delayMicroseconds(200);
  digitalWrite(wrPin, 1); //set 23 high
  digitalWrite(csPin, 0);
  digitalWrite(aoPin, 0);
  Serial2.write(0x17);
  digitalWrite(aoPin, 1);
  Serial2.write(0x40);
  digitalWrite(aoPin, 0);
  ;
}

void loop() {
  int currentState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(currentState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("The Button was Pressed!");
    digitalWrite(wrPin, 0);
    delayMicroseconds(250);
    digitalWrite(wrPin, 1);
    digitalWrite(aoPin, 0);
    digitalWrite(csPin, 0);
    Serial2.write(0x9a);
}
}

I've tried playing around with the timing, order and what pins I'm pulsing, and all I've gotten back is a self-test screen or printing 'ä' when I reset the ESP (or press the button, if I have my code configured with pulsePin getting pulsed on button press.
Datasheet here.

I wonder if there's a Stack Exchange for hardware hacking.  You haven't asked a question here, but I'm guessing that the implied question is about how to correctly talk to this particular hardware?

@DrewDormann Yeah, that's what I'm getting at. I'm trying to figure out what specific pins need to be pulsed or digital written in what way to get it to accept hex values.

The "framing" for async serial (i.e. UARTs and RS-232) data is per character or byte, and consists of a start bit and stop bits. Do not conflate "framing" with a message or packet or datagram format.  "[F]iguring out how ... to send hex data" - A display device is most likely expecting ASCII encoded data rather than "hex data". If you want to display "hex data", then you probably need to send the "hex data" converted to a string of ASCII characters.

@sawdust That's what I had thought, but I don't see why they'd supply the pages that show accompanying hex codes for the characters in the different character sets if that was the case.

"I don't see why they'd supply the pages ..." - You seem to be referring to the extended/alternate character sets that use 8 bits. ASCII is the base character set for 0x20 to 0x7f data values. "how to pulse the write pins ..." - You seem unaware that the display has two interfaces, a serial one and a parallel one. You should (probably) only connect (and use) one interface from the host to the display. Toggling the control lines for the parallel interface but leaving the data pins idle (or unconnected or floating?), and then sending serial data is likely to confuse the display.
